# I am getting a unexpected error while using pycharm with python 3.6 interpreter, I remember making this in 3.7 and no error occured back then

Tags: multidimensional-array, random, pycharm, python-3.6

```
import random


class Logic:

  def __init__(self):
     super().__init__()

     self.actual = [[0 for _ in range(8)] for _ in range(10)]
     self.danger()

  def danger(self):
     p = random.randint(0, 9)
     q = random.randint(0, 7)

     self.actual[p][q] = '#'
```

parameter q in the last line shows this error :

Unexpected type(s): (int, str) Possible type(s): (_SupportsIndex, int) (slice, Iterable[int])
Inspection info: This inspection detects type errors in function call expressions. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Types of function parameters can be specified in docstrings or in Python 3 function annotations.

Comment: Please read [mre]. This can't be reproduced.

Comment: That's not a Python error message. It's likely coming from your IDE. What IDE are you using? PyCharm?

Comment: yeahh my bad. its from pycharm 2021 community edition.